# What is this error when importing andas_datareader?

Tags: python, pandas, import

Python 3.7 Windows 10
i'm doing a simple import of the pandas_datareader, but it tells me that the name "type_check" is not recognized.

I have all the latest versions of the libraries.

Not sure if it is a problem with pandas_datareader, its compatibility or a folder naming/location problem.

Code:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Output:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7305c9f0ed64> in <module>
      1 # import python's number crunchers
----> 2 from pandas_datareader import data as web
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import numpy as np

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas_datareader\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from ._version import get_versions
----> 2 from .data import (
      3     DataReader,
      4     Options,
      5     get_components_yahoo,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py in <module>
      7 import warnings
      8 
----> 9 from pandas.util._decorators import deprecate_kwarg
     10 
     11 from pandas_datareader.av.forex import AVForexReader

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     11 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     12     try:
---> 13         __import__(dependency)
     14     except ImportError as e:
     15         missing_dependencies.append(dependency)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    143     from .core import *
    144     from . import compat
--> 145     from . import lib
    146     from .lib import *
    147     from . import linalg

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py in <module>
     30 
     31 __all__ = ['emath', 'math', 'tracemalloc_domain']
---> 32 __all__ += type_check.__all__
     33 __all__ += index_tricks.__all__
     34 __all__ += function_base.__all__

NameError: name 'type_check' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you try to reorder the import sequence to 1. `import numpy as np`, 2. `import pandas as pd`, 3. `from pandas_datareader import data as web`?

Comment: Just did and it worked! Thanks! Why does this happen if the pandas_datareader and pandas libraries are different libraries? Is the formder dependent on the latter?

Comment: Yup, you can check it in the [requirements](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-datareader/). Glad my comment was helpful ...